# CommunicationsException: Connecting to a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc, ssh

So I am creating a SSH connection to my remote MySQL server. I am able to do ssh -v user@host through shell, so I know my host ip, username, and password is correct.

This is the code I am using to do that :

```
    int lport=5656;
    String rhost="host";
    String host="host";
    int rport=3306;
    String user="root";
    String password="pass";
    String dbuserName = "root";
    String dbpassword = "pass";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+lport+"/lg4";
    String driverName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection conn = null;
    Session session= null;
    try{
        //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
        System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

        //mysql database connectivity
        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, dbuserName, dbpassword);
        System.out.println ("Database connection established");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(conn != null && !conn.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            conn.close();
        }
        if(session !=null && session.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

The console plays out this:

"Port Forwarded" from System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

So I know it did port forward, the problem is in this line:

```
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, dbuserName, dbpassword);
```

The error is:

CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

So I started to try to find solutions for this issue and I came across a list of possible solutions and problems:

1. IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
4. DB server is down.
5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
6. DB server has run out of connections.
7. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.

Ok so I started going one by one, narrowing down the issues:

1. I know my IP is right because I am able to access it through shell and it does port forward.
2. Same as one
3. I add the port I port forwarded to the local host, so I doubt that is the issue.
4. Server is not down, I even rebooted to make sure everything was fine.
5. I configured the MySQL, commenting #bin-address, I couldn't comment skip-networking because bin-address is now the default.
6. How does this happen? I don't know about this one.
7. My firewall is turned off.

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace localhost with the ip in your url.that might help
like  `String url = "jdbc:mysql://yourIp:"+lport+"/lg4";`

Comment: My IP on a mac or the local host ip 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Is the localhost for mac 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Changed it to that, now I am getting this error:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.